# Unique feature image as header image for each page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to add feature-image as header image for every page.

My question is where do i put below code... in `page.php` or `header.php` or `template.php`. Moreover i want to make image full-width

Following is code.

```php
<?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
        <div class="featured-image-in-header">
            <?php echo the_post_thumbnail( 'large','max-width:100%;height:auto'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in header.php at the end. but I would only modify one thing first to avoid future mistakes.

```
<?php 
    if( is_single() || is_page() ){

       if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
           <div class="featured-image-in-header">
               <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large',array( 'style' => 'max-width:100%;height:auto; width:100%;')); ?>
           </div>
       <?php }  
    }
```

In some cases in template files you will need to put, depending on the theme you are using it has a file that is called before the header, so it will depend a lot on how your theme was developed.

But generally speaking if you put it at the end of the header.php file it will work

Comment: its working. can i put before or after "main container div"?

Comment: I updated the post. If this helped you please complete the question as answered, it helps us a lot :)

Comment: its working. can i put before or after "main container div"?  Whatever is best for your option, but I might put it before main div

Comment: Hehehe if this solved your problem please mark the question as solved and give me a vote it helps me a lot :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `echo` for this function.
Correct code:

```
<?php 
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
       <div class="featured-image-in-header">
           <?php the_post_thumbnail('large', ['style' => 'max-width:100%;height:auto']);?>
       </div>
   <?php }
```